# Unity game - make saved data private (invisible to other than my app)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm using `Application.persistentDataPath` path to save graphical content required by my application. Unfortunatelly, I can't anyhow force Unity to make it private ([Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE)), thus it is **visible** and **could be grabbed** by any user with basic knowledge of Android from path `Android/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files/`. I tried more things, among it setting *Player Settings / Write permission* to **Internal** didn't solved it.

I'm aware that I can create native Intents and run them from Unity game, but it looks like it is achieved by reflection and I need to load the data really fast

This content can't be delivered with app (it is downloaded after user's purchase) and it is expected to be loaded as fast as possible - it has a lot of images - together having ~ 200MB at least.

How can I force Unity to use private storage? Or how can I hide the whole folder from User at least?

Comment: Why not use encryption?

Comment: @Shaman 1) I need to load it and send immediately to graphic card - encryption would add really slow layer  2) in classic android app you can "hide" these files natively, so why bother with encryption. 3) encryption ends with physical access of attacker to a data - as mentioned in point 2, OS can solve this for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a simple solution, so here it is for you:

I called Android native function `getDir` with my desired private *folder*'s name and stored it to a static property **ap**. If I'm not on Android, I use `Application.persistentDataPath`.

**RESULT:**

`persistentDataPath` returns */storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mycomp.myapp/files*

`getDir` returns */data/user/0/com.mycomp.myapp/app_pFiles*

**Full code:**

```
public static class FolderHelper
{
    // cached value
    private static string ap;

    static FolderHelper()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
        try
        {
            using (AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer"))
            {
                using (AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity"))
                {
                    ap = jo.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getDir", "pFiles", 0).Call<string>("getAbsolutePath");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(e.ToString());
            ap = Path.GetFullPath(Application.persistentDataPath);
        }
#else
        ap = Path.GetFullPath(Application.persistentDataPath);
#endif
    }


    // other code depending on property ap

}
```

Comment: getDir = Application.dataPath path